# Why is my BubbleChart so slow?

Tags: charts

I am using the California Housing data to create a Dataset. My Dataset is called "housing" and contains 20000 odd rows with 11 columns. I am trying to make a BubbleChart by using three fields i.e. "longitude", "latitude" and "mean_house_value". While the plot does eventually render it is taking an inordinate amount of time to do so. On my laptop with an i7 Gen 10 processor and 12 GB of RAM, it takes 731 seconds i.e. almost 12 minutes for the plot to render.
My code is given below:

```
BubbleChart[{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]/1000} & /@ 
   Normal[housing[
     All, {"longitude", "latitude", 
      "median_house_value"}]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way of doing this?
Appreciate any help.

Comment: It's hard to say without some example Dataset available, but my first guess would be to stick an `Evaluate[...]` around the contents of the `BubbleChart`. It's possible it's attempting to re-evaluate the argument multiple times if it's not a simple list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with ```BubbleChart[
 Evaluate[{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]/1000} & /@ 
   Normal[housing[
     All, {"longitude", "latitude", "median_house_value"}]]]]``` but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: try if `housing2 = housing[All, {"longitude", "latitude", 
    Slot["median_house_value"]/1000}];BubbleChart[housing2]` is any faster?

Comment: If the interaction is not important, you could also use `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @kglr. However that code throws a syntax error.

Comment: A.Mustafi, sorry, missed a `&`. Try `housing2 = 
  housing[All, {"longitude", "latitude", 
    Slot["median_house_value"]/1000 &}];`

Comment: try also `housing[BubbleChart, {"longitude", "latitude", 
  Slot["median_house_value"]/1000 &}]`?

Comment: Defining `ChartElements` (like `Graphics[Disk[]]`) with `PerformanceGoal` seems to have a stronger effect.

Comment: @Ben Izd, thanks for the help. Strangely, adding the PerformanceGoal option does not really change anything. It is still taking virtually the same time.

Comment: @kglr, inserted a slot into the command as pointed out by you. But again there seems to be no performance gain

Comment: Strangely, the plot renders almost instantaneously, in python with pandas.