# How to fill in missing data in Dataset in place

Tags: dataset

I have a dummy dataset that contains a few missing values and some filler strings. The missing values have been entered as a blank space while the filler string has been entered as "NA". I need to replace the missing values and the filler strings with the Mean of the other values in the same column. The modified Dataset could be stored in another variable, but it is preferable to make the modifications in-place.

Just can't work out the easiest and most consistent way to perform this. Any help would deeply appreciated.

The code for creating the dataset is given below:

```
rawData = {<|"a" -> 12, "b" -> 3.4, "c" -> 101|>, <|"a" -> "", 
   "b" -> 9, "c" -> 121.4 |>, <|"a" -> 5.6, "b" -> "", "c" -> "NA"|>}
data = Dataset[rawData]
```

Comment: The biggest problem is not even `Dataset`, but the fact that Mathematica does not provide efficient means for in-place modifications of expressions for elements which do not form rectangular structures - which the elements that have to be replaced in your example, don't. You will be better off by doing `rawData = ReplacePart[rawData, 
 Position[rawData, oldValue] ->  newValue]`. For `Dataset`, you can't do that directly, so will need to do that on `Normal[data]`, then wrap the result back in `Dataset`. Attempts to implement in-place replacements will likely be less efficient for general case.

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin, such a privilege to have you answering the question. This just reinforces  what I had been thinking about the implemetation of Dataset. Unfortunately this just makes Datasets a lot less useful, then I had previously expected. Why can't they just have the ease and simplicity of Pandas.

Comment: Thanks :) I can post a longer answer, if you'd like, since I did some benchmarks / mutable implementation attempts before posting this comment here - so let me know. Re: Pandas - I've been toying with an idea of writing an alternative to Dataset which would be closer to that. Might still happen, finding spare time and justifying the effort is a biggest issue. I personally would also prefer a different design in many actual use cases. Of course, some of the limitations are coming from the language itself and are not always easy to overcome.

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin would love to read your post regarding the benchmarks. I am also starting to notice that Wolfram’s charts are tending to get extremely slow, even for moderately large data. (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/244486/73016 ). Is there a fundamental issue we are looking at?